# What is the best eBook for a Hibernate beginner?

Tags: java, hibernate

What is the best eBook for a beginner in Hibernate?

Comment: Partly, the answer depends on whether you're interested in Hibernate (Java) or NHibernate (.NET). While they're similar, each has features and idioms native to it's platform.

Comment: Also check out http://www.summerofnhibernate.com/

Comment: pdf for Hibernate (Java)

Comment: @ Bevan the question is tagged "java" and "hibernate". sounds clear to me.

Comment: @Pierre It was originally tagged nhibernate hibernate fluent-nhibernate. Click on "edited X hours ago" (or similar) to see the revision story

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The online Reference Documentation is a good place to start, especially the [Hibernate 5 new User Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html).

And for the "absolute reference", get [*Java Persistence with Hibernate*](http://www.manning.com/bauer2/) (a revised edition of the old *Hibernate in Action*). Here is what the authors write about this book:

> We had three goals when writing this
>   book, so you can read it as
>
> - A tutorial for Hibernate, Java Persistence, and EJB 3.0 that guides
>     you through your first steps with
>     these solutions
> - A guide for learning all basic and advanced Hibernate features for
>     object/ relational mapping, object
>     processing, querying, performance
>     optimization, and application design
> - A reference for whenever you need a complete and technically accurate
>     definition of Hibernate and Java
>     Persistence functionality

As stated, it's the absolute reference (880 pages), it allows to go as deep as you want.

For tuning Hibernate, you could also check the [High-Performance Java Persistence](https://vladmihalcea.com/books/high-performance-java-persistence/) book.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to take a look at this free knol : [Nhibernate by Fabio Maulo](http://knol.google.com/k/fabio-maulo/nhibernate/1nr4enxv3dpeq/21#), it's a link to the first chapter (total: 20 chapters).
Also:

- [Introduction to Nhibernate By Ian Cooper](http://codebetter.com/blogs/ian_cooper/archive/tags/NHibernate/default.aspx-)
- [Your very first Nhibernate application (3 parts)](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ado_net/Your-very-first-NHibernate-application-Part-1.aspx-)
- [Summer of Nhibernate screencast series](http://www.summerofnhibernate.com/-)
- This one is old, but it's well written and easy to understand for beginners: [Part 1](http://www.theserverside.net/tt/articles/showarticle.tss?id=NHibernate) | [Part 2](http://www.theserverside.net/tt/articles/showarticle.tss?id=NHibernateP2-)
- [This Wiki](http://nhforge.org/wikis/) and [this list of articles](http://community.jboss.org/en/hibernate/nhibernate?view=all) should be your friends too:)

Comment: Links no longer works... Also original post tagged Java and all the links in this answer points to its .NET equivalent(Nhibernate).

Answer (score 1):

"Hibernate In Action" would be my choice.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate documentation available at http://www.hibernate.org/ would be a good place to start
along with roseindia tutorials.